# Find smallest value in list

Tags: python

Very simple program here.  I'm trying to take a positive integer n, generate a list of n random numbers between 100 and 500, and return the minimum value that appears in the list

```
import random
def randomNumber2(n):
    mylist2 = []
    needMoreNumbers2 = True
    while (needMoreNumbers2):
        randomNumber2 = int(random.random() * 500)
        myList2.append(randomNumber2)
        n >= n - 100
        if (n <= 500):
            needMoreNumbers2 = false
    return myList2
```

Could someone help guide me in the direction I need to go?

Comment: Hint: let the first random number be the minimum. On subsequent iterations, if the new random number is smaller, have that value replace the old minimum.

Comment: Is `n >= n - 100` a typo? You aren't modifying the value of `n`, your just making a comparison and ignoring the result.

Answer (score 6):

```
import random

def randomNumber2(n):
    return min(random.randint(100, 500) for _ in range(n))
```

Comment: That is a simpler way to code it.  Looking at my code, is there a way you could change a few things on mine to produce the minimum value?

Answer (score 4):

If you want something closer to your program, you need to fix a number of things in your program first - it doesn't run at all.  Python is case-sensitive, so `mylist2` and `myList2` are different.  Use the same spelling throughout.  Similarly, `false` is not a Python builtin - `False` is.

Fix those and we get:

```
import random

def randomNumber2(n):
    myList2 = []
    needMoreNumbers2 = True
    while (needMoreNumbers2):
        randomNumber2 = int(random.random() * 500)
        myList2.append(randomNumber2)
        n >= n - 100
        if (n <= 500):
            needMoreNumbers2 = False
    return myList2
```

Now regardless of what's passed for `n`, so long as `n` is <= 500 that returns a list with a single random integer, in 0 thru 499 (inclusive).  If `n` is > 500, it runs forever (infinite loop).  Can you see why?  `if (n <= 500)` is always true if the original `n` is <= 500, and always false otherwise.  Your `n >= n - 100` doesn't do anything visible (it just compares `n` to `n - 100`, and always returns true, which is ignored).

So take the advice to move **toward** more reasonable Python idioms.  Here's a way that should be easier to understand:

```
import random

def randomNumber2(n):
    myList2 = []
    while len(myList2) < n:
        randomNumber2 = int(random.random() * 500)
        myList2.append(randomNumber2)
    return myList2
```

Progress ;-)  Now we at least get back a list with `n` random integers.  They're not in the range you want, though:  `int(random.random() * 500)` returns an int in the range 0 through 499 inclusive.  If you want them to be between 100 and 500 inclusive, the best way is to do `random.randint(100, 500)`, as someone else already showed you.  `100 + int(random.random() * 400)` is an equivalent way that's closer to your original code, so let's try that:

```
import random

def randomNumber2(n):
    myList2 = []
    while len(myList2) < n:
        randomNumber2 = 100 + int(random.random() * 400)
        myList2.append(randomNumber2)
    return myList2
```

To get the minimum, it's overwhelmingly best to just do `min(myList2)` at the end.  Not only will that be correct, it's also faster than anything you can code yourself.  If you want to do it yourself, here's one way:

```
import random

def randomNumber2(n):
    myList2 = []
    smallest = None
    while len(myList2) < n:
        randomNumber2 = 100 + int(random.random() * 400)
        myList2.append(randomNumber2)
        if smallest is None or randomNumber2 < smallest:
            smallest = randomNumber2
    assert smallest == min(myList2)
    return myList2
```

The answer from F J is how most experienced Pythonistas would code it, though.

Comment: +1 Better walk through of his code than mine. However, I'd also mention that a for loop is also preferred to a while loop in this case.

Comment: Yes, a for loop is definitely more natural.  But I wanted to give the OP code as close as reasonable to his original, since that's what he kept asking for ;-)

Comment: how do you get to just show just the lowest int in the whole list?

Comment: You could, for example, `return smallest` instead of `return myList2`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to take a positive integer n, generate a list of n random numbers between 100 and 500, and return the minimum value that appears in the list

Then, you don't need the list, you just need to return the smallest of the random numbers generated in `n` "throws"

```
import random

def smallrand(n,rangemin=100,rangemax=500):
    smallest = float('+inf')
    for _ in xrange(n):
       new = random.randint(rangemin, rangemax)
       if new < smallest: smallest = new
    return smallest
```